# How to repaint - prapare JWindow graphics before setting it to visible?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, swingworker

To avoid any flickers after `JWindow` is set to visible I've done it this way - but still I see for a few milliseconds some `JLabel` (tree: `JWindow` -> `JPanel` -> `JLabel`) old text, then text changes to new value (it must be done before `JWindow` is set to visible):

```
public SomeExtendedJWindow extends SomeJWindow {

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            class doGraphics extends SwingWorker<Void, Object> {

                @Override
                public Void doInBackground() {
                    validate();
                    pack();
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    SomeJWindow.super.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            (new doGraphics()).execute();
        } 
    }
}
```

Maybe I should validate or do something with `JLabel`s also?

Comment: If you want to avoid flicker, you should avoid painting to the window directly, instead paint to something like a JPanel, which is double buffered

Comment: Mother idea is to pack the window and position it off the screen somewhere before making it visible, then moving to the visible area of the screen

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is common issue, caused by default when you re_use popup container, you can to see, catch previous value after Xxx.setVisible ....

Comment: Tried `someJPanel`, also `someJLabel` to `validate();` - no success.. Maybe I will try to set `JLabel` text to "" right before dialog is closed.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to re-use the window.

Comment: don't access swing components off the EDT (as you do by triggering their layout). BTW: same procedure as last time - show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem, as the flicker is unusual :-)

Comment: I will try somehow to capture it to video, and will see in slow motion what is happening. Do not have such software, will try to find (now leaving the PC).

Comment: No need for a video. Post a `SSCCE` so we can run the code ourselves and see exactly what you a doing.

Comment: I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734277/setvisibletrue-immediate-repaint) the same problem. Is it really impossible to reuse the `JWindow` instead of creating new one?

Comment: no, it's not impossible - maybe you are doing something wrong or maybe the problem is highly context dependent: because (until now) nobody can reproduce the flicker with the SSCCE in your other question - not even with the EDT violation that you insist on not fixing ;-)

Comment: OK, my question is - if component is not visible, and I do some changes to it - so the changes applied AFTER the component is set to visible? I mean old graphics is still visible, but gradually repainted with new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:
`jLabel.setText("new text")` 
before make the dialog visible (`SomeJWindow.setVisible(true);`).

Anyway, it seems not necessary to use a SwingWorker. 
I would not Override the `setVisible(boolean visible)`.

Just set the text on the Label before call the `someExtendedJWindow .setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Yes, I have stopped using `SwingWorker` in such cases, but noticed that  `getGraphics().update()` does the job.